# "I have been TO..." is just for countries or for everywhere too?

Tags: prepositions

Does the preposition '**to**'  in the phrase '**I have been to**...' fit to countries only or it goes well also for cities, supermarket, university etc.?

I'm asking it because the main use I've heard this kind of sentence with the preposition 'to' was mainly for countries. I can't recall something else.

Examples:

> I **have been to** the supermarket and bought some vegtables.
>
> **Have you been to** the university today?

Comment: Use it with any place you go to, even if it's only your own front door!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*have been to*](https://www.thoughtco.com/esl-have-gone-to-vs-have-been-to-4176485) is a phrase used to mean to visit some place and return. The preposition is the part of the phrase and it remains irrespective of the places you have visited.

So, to answer, it's not just for a country, but for any place including the instances you have quoted ([another example](https://www.thoughtco.com/esl-have-gone-to-vs-have-been-to-4176485): *Ask Tom for some money. **He's been to the bank today***).

Even further, someone can also *...has been to Trump's rallies....*

Answer (score 1):

"Have been to" can be used anytime you go somewhere. You can say:
I have been to Mexico.
I have been to the store.
I have been to Sam's house.

Answer (score 0):

I have been *to* can be used for almost anywhere you go; it's wrong to say:

> I've been *to* home.
>
> It should be: I've been home.
>
> I've been *to* there. ×
>
> I've been there.  ✓
>
> I've been *to* here. ×
>
> I've been here. ✓